# How do I find the smallest circle enclosing a compact region?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves

The Four-vertex theorem states that any simple closed plane curve has at least four vertices, i.e $\kappa'(t) = 0$ where $\kappa$ is the signed curvature function.

The proof given by Osserman [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609268.pdf) depends on the lemma: Given a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, there exists a unique smallest circle enclosing $K$ (the circumscribed circle)

**My question is**: how does one actually find this circle?

If I have a simple closed plane curve, defined parametrically $\alpha : I \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and I want to find its vertices, I first try to find the signed curvature function $$\kappa(t) = \frac{\det(\alpha', \alpha'')}{||\alpha'(t)||^3} $$

then find the points where the derivative $\kappa'(t) = 0$

This almost never goes smoothly and I end up with messy calculations. So instead, using the proof, I can find such circumscribed circle and show that it intersects $\alpha$ in $n$ points, proving that the curve has indeed $2n$ vertices.

For the case that the curve has symmetry, like here

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

It could work to define a circle with center at the origin and radius $R = \sup_{t \in I}||\alpha(t)||$. Is there another way all together to find the vertices of a simple closed curve?

Comment: Roughly I think it should go like this: $K$ compact means there is some ball $B_p(r)$ at a point $p$ with radius $r$ such that $K \subset B_p(r)$. Consider the function $K \to \mathbb R$ that assigns to each point $p \in K$, the minimum $r$ value such that $K \subset \bar{B_p(r)}$. (Claim, the minimum always exists.) If this is a continuous function, by compactness it takes on a minimum value. This should be your circumscribed sphere.

Comment: "In general" there will be no closed form solution, but numerical methods of minimization (for continuous, but not necessarily differentiable, functions) should work.

Comment: @Rylee Lyman thanks, I will try to work this out!

Comment: One of the reasons that real analysis is so powerful is that it allows one to prove existence of things which are difficult to construct explicitly. Constructive methods may exist but are generally harder. For example, real analysis gives us a very simple proof of existence of $\sqrt{3}$: apply the intermediate value theorem to $f(x)=x^2$ on the interval $[0,2]$. A constructive method for calculating the first $k$ digits of its decimal approximation is possible too, but it's harder.